# Mail script with just JavaScript and HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, contacts

Is it possible to create a contact form that sends the answers by email with *only* HTML5 and JavaScript? And if it is, how do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to do it from JavaScript directly via a `mail` function or so because the user's local machine can't be assumed to be running a mail server. There would be nothing to send the email from.

I'm not sure how "standards compliant" this is, but you can navigate to (by using links or `document.location`) to `mailto:user@example.com` or so which will begin composing an email in the user's standard email client, allowing them to send you an email directly. Though this will expose both their and your email address.

Answer (score 2):

In the action field of the form, set the action as “mailto:youremailaddress” for example:

```
 <form action="mailto:myforms@mydomain.com">
```

If you want to send the form data as plain text you can use the following

Add ‘enctype=text/plain’ in the form attributes. The form code becomes:

```
 <form action="mailto:myforms@mydomain.com" enctype="text/plain" >
```

When this form is submitted, you will get the email in readable form.